# How to implement weighted pagerank algorithm in neo4j ?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, pagerank

Is there any argument in inbuilt pagerank algorithm or a separate algorithm is available for applying pagerank algorithm on a weighted neo4j graph. [I found the algorithm here](https://medium.com/@captainjackrana/weighted-pagerank-algorithm-in-neo4j-using-cypher-696fe5519877) but don't know how to run it interatively on neo4j dekstop.

Comment: Are you asking how to execute Cypher in general? How to create a graph that the code can run on? How to adapt the code for your graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Neo4j [Graph Algorithms Library](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-graph-algorithms/) that contains a [page rank algorithm](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-graph-algorithms/#_page_rank) procedure. The procedure signature is as follow:

> CALL algo.pageRank(label:String, relationship:String, {iterations:5,
>   dampingFactor:0.85, write: true, writeProperty:'pagerank',
>   concurrency:4}) YIELD nodes, iterations, loadMillis, computeMillis,
>   writeMillis, dampingFactor, write, writeProperty - calculates page
>   rank and potentially writes back

You can use the algorithm running a query like this:

```
CALL algo.pageRank.stream('Page', 'LINKS', {iterations:20, dampingFactor:0.85})
YIELD node, score
RETURN node,score order by score desc limit 20
```

Comment: I want to run weighted page rank algo.